# How do I columnate a list of items with minimal width?

Tags: bash, ls

How do I columnate any uncollumnated input like `ls` does?

`ls` is creating an optimized table with minimum width for each row, for example:

```
ls

2  dsao  file with space  with
5  e     g                wsdl-rubo-6cb0f1a9086e80c
d  file   leading space
```

but if I feed output into `column` (for ex. each file on one line), it pads every row the same width, so it fits the screen width:

```
for i in *; do echo "$i"; done | column

2                               file with space                          
5                               g                                        
d                                leading space                           
dsao                            with                                     
e                               wsdl-rubo-6cb0f1a9086e80c                
file
```

(I use only the file list here to generate the same output as example, I am looking for such a solution to columnize other things in the end.)

**How can I colunnize any output with a variable col-width?**

Comment: Okay, an alternate reading of your request, if I understand your comments correctly, would be "columnate the input like `column -c`_`n` -x` does, but fit the output into as few screen columns as possible rather than filling out the specified width".  Is this correct?

Comment: yes nearly: additionally there should be resulting as many columns as possible that fit into the screen. (like `ls` manages it). Maybe we find the solution, if we look into the sourcecode of the [sourcecode of `ls` command in coreutils](http://pastebin.com/pxQt1CaD)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks @rubo77 for asking this, it's a great exercise. For me it was to off-by-one errors what English is Tough Stuff is to botched rhythm: it got fun, fast, even though the algorithm itself here is pretty simple.

[ final edit: moved to https://github.com/jthill/columnate/blob/master/columnate, bug fixed, row-major implemented. ]

Comment: also you should put this on github. If it is faster than the ls-algorythm, maybe you can create a faster ls-util?

Comment: @rubo77 You need to feed it the COLUMNS variable. see the 'test with' comment in the code.  And that 10x-20x is the other way around, it's slower, mostly because it's awk vs C.

Comment: `time ls | sort | columnate COLUMNS=$COLUMNS`

Comment: You are a genius. This has to be published for every linux distribution

Comment: eh, thanks, really, but that's too strong.  read the code, it's nearly brute-force

Comment: Why is it brute force? I think its ok if it works! And can you get rid of the need to add $COLUMN? maybe with `tput cols` see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20102272/trying-to-get-terminal-columns-in-java

Comment: @rubo77 see `test` in the repo, all that praise got me to clean it up and find a bug or two into the bargain :-)

Comment: great! I added some issues to your [github project](https://github.com/jthill/columnate/blob/master/columnate). lets continue any discussions there

Answer (score 3):

Something close to the output of `ls`:

```
for i in *; do echo -en "${i}\t"; done; echo
```

Comment: nice, it is only jumping in row, if the input lines are varying more than one tab in width. Is there a way to prevent a break of the output at the right window side?

Answer (score 1):

This does not use the minimum width for each row, like the solution above by @jthill, but it is also note mentioning:

I installed `autogen` with `homebrew` which includes the command `columns` which exactly solves this issue:

1. install homebrew: https://brew.sh/
2. `brew install autogen`

test with

```
spit() { for i ; do echo "$i"; done; }
spit 1 2222222222222222 3 4 5 6 7777777777777777 8 $(seq 10 30) | columns
```

output:

```
1                   2222222222222222    3                   4
5                   6                   7777777777777777    8
10                  11                  12                  13
14                  15                  16                  17
18                  19                  20                  21
22                  23                  24                  25
26                  27                  28                  29
```

Note: maybe the apt package is enough too:

```
apt install autogen
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create temporary folder and create empty files for each string item of your uncollumnated input and then use `ls` for the columned output.

Example:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/col
IFS=''
echo "something_very_long-something_very_long-something_very_long
output with space
 space-at-beginning
3
4
5
6
7
8
9"|while read; do 
  touch /tmp/col/"$REPLY"
  done
cd /tmp/col/
ls
rm /tmp/col/*
```

Output:

```
 3   7                    something_very_long-something_very_long-something_very_long
 4   8                   ' space-at-beginning'
 5   9
 6  'output with space'
```